# openni_launch rosdep on OS X

Tags: openni, rosdep, openni-launch, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep seems to know about openni_launch, but the formula ros/hydro/rgbd_launch is not there. Is the formula supposed to be there, or is rosdep wrong?

I'm on OS X 10.9 Mavericks with a desktop-full install of ROS hydro.

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src/openni_launch --ignore-src
Error: No available formula for rgbd_launch
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/hydro
executing command [brew install ros/hydro/rgbd_launch]
Error: No available formula for rgbd_launch
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/hydro
Searching taps...
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  homebrew: command [brew install ros/hydro/rgbd_launch] failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108916/openni_launch-rosdep-on-os-x/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is likely that `rgbd_launch` is missing from your workspace. To understand why it failed like this, you have to understand the process through with rosdep goes when resolving dependencies:

- Is `rgbd_launch` a package on the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?
- If yes, consider it resolved
- Is `rgbd_launch` a system dependency (defined in the rosdep rules at https://github.com/ros/rosdistro)?
- If yes, try to install it
- Otherwise it must be a ROS package which is not in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
- Try to install that ROS package from the system's package manager.

On OS X, it tries to guess at the formula name, in this case `ros/hydro/rgbd_launch`, which fails because it doesn't have a homebrew formula. On Ubuntu, this would have done `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rgbd-launch` and it would have succeeded.

The solution to your problem is to add `rgbd_launch` to your workspace. I would recommend making a rosinstall file using the `rosinstall_generator`:

```
sudo pip install rosinstall-generator
source /path/to/hydro/install/setup.bash
rosinstall_generator openni_launch --rosdistro hydro --deps --exclude RPP > openni_launch.rosinstall
```

The resulting rosinstall file will include `openni_launch`, and any of its dependencies which are not in your `RPP`.

You can then get all of the repositories in this rosinstall file by using wstool:

```
wstool init src openni_launch.rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-11**:
Thanks for this excellent answer. I wasn't aware of this last step of guessing the furmula name. I only just recently switched to catkin.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-12**:
I posted a followup on how to best deal with adding packages to a source install: http://answers.ros.org/question/109656/maintaining-a-ros-source-install-add-packages-update-release/